# Visual Studio 2017 + Core 2 + Angular project - loading and USING 3rd party libraries

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with the Core 2.0 + Angular 4 template for Visual Studio 2017.  I have the basic program up and running easily enough, but I am having a heck of a time getting third party libraries integrated into the application. I'm starting with moment js. First, I did
npm install --save moment
Which loaded moment in node_modules
Then I opened webpack.config.vendor.js and added moment to the non tree shaking, like this:

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    ...
    'jquery',
    'moment/moment'
];
```

(note i also tried just 'moment' and that didn't work either in the end though both worked when i ran webpack.  I choose 'moment/moment' because node_module/moment/moment.js exists)

THEN, I ran

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
```

and that worked without errors.

Note: When I open up the vendor.js file that is generated, I see this as part of the file now:

```
    **-/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(module) {var require;//! moment.js
    -//! version : 2.19.1
    -//! authors : Tim Wood, Iskren Chernev, Moment.js contributors
    -//! license : MIT
    -//! momentjs.com**

;(function (global, factory) {....
```

So I'm confident webpack is at least finding the file.

But THEN came the question of how I actually USE moment now that its bundled in vendor.js.  At this point, I'm at a loss as to how to actually USE moment js.

I tried:

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment' (or 'moment' when i tried that)
```

Then:

```
declare var moment: any
```

Then this, which also didn't fail until runtime:

```
import { Moment } from 'moment/moment'
constructor(private moment: Moment) {}
```

which was reaching, I know, but I had to try it

But every time, any attempt to use moment tells me moment is undefined.

Could someone please show me how to add momentjs to this application and how to actually USE it within my an Angular component?

BONUS POINTS: I see JQuery is added by default. How do I use that in Typescript given an el: ElementRef to execute against?  I'm assuming its similar, but I'm not sure (and I know I should avoid jQuery but I'm migrating a legacy site that has just a bit of jquery that I don't have time to replace just yet)

Comment: you need to install the type definition for jquery using typings. If it's already installed then you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include moment.js manually. Just use angular2-moment package:

```
npm install --save angular2-moment
```

Then import it with:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

**Update**
To use another external library that doesn't have an angular wrapper you would:

1. Install it with `npm install --save libName`
2. Include it in your angular-cli.json under scripts. For example:

   "scripts": [
           "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
           "../node_modules/bootcards/dist/js/bootcards.min.js"
         ]
3. Declare it as a global variable in your component (like you were doing)

   declare var moment: any

Comment: First, thanks.  i didn't realize there was an angular2-moment version.  I'll look for similar for other libraries.  However, I'm sure there will be a library ot two that doesn't have an angular2 version.  How would I use those?

Comment: Updated my answer with how to use an external library.

Comment: This is incredibly wrong. Everything about this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @AluanHaddad how is this wrong? apart from the incorrect install line (which i put in an edit for), this answer is the most appropriate and correct

Comment: @AluanHaddad Your comment is incredibly wrong. Everything about your comment is incorrect.

Comment: 1: You are suggesting improper import syntax that causes a number of tools to fail and only works because of sloppy transpiler behavior. 2: You said to `declare var moment: any` which is ridiculous as moment ships with type declarations and is a module. 3. You are advising using moment as a global variable in a modular environment. 4: it has nothing to do with it having some arbitrary angular wrapper.

Comment: Buddy.. the guy asked me how use external libraries that don't have typings or an angular integration already. It's not perfect but it does work, get over it. I don't see your answer the the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem, you can try something like this in your webpack configuration:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        moment: "moment"
    }),
```

And then in your component:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: This worked for me given a library that is loaded from npm but doesn't have its own angular 2 wrapper.  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, please set the answer as accepted. Thank you