# Add a library to VS2017 SPA template

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio-2017, single-page-application

I'm trying out the VS2017 Angular SPA template with .Net Core & EF Core.  All works fine in the app so far.  But I tried to add moment to the my Web UI project and don't know to get it working.
I tried:

```
npm install --save angular2-moment
```

which was fine, but then referencing moment in angular things go wrong.  There must be some change to webpack required, but the only file I have is webpack.config.js (which doesn't seem to fit examples). I'm new to webpack and could use some guidance as to what to change & how.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984628/visual-studio-2017-core-2-angular-project-loading-and-using-3rd-party-libr ?

Comment: I looked at the link but I don't have a webpack.config.vendor.js file in my solution

Comment: yep found it ! apologies.